# Geo-location detection for addthis

Tags: javascript, geolocation, addthis

I can't get this to work on the addthis welcome bar. I've done every configuration on addthis's api ( http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/524574-welcome-bar-api#.UN6ISG_oStY ) with success, but I cant get the location detected.

This is an example of just the location java script to detect visitors from the united states. Upon arrival, visitors from the specified location, would be prompted a message and link designated to the location.

```
      <script type="text/javascript"   src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-50c562341cdc5d64"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            addthis.bar.initialize([
{

    "match": {

        "LocatedIn": "US"
    },
    "message": "Welcome",
    "action": {
        "type": "button",
        "text": "Follow us",
        "verb": "follow",

        "url": "http://www.twitter.com/example"
       }
      }
         ]);


        </script>
```

can anyone get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix - I tested your code and it didn't work for me until I changed "LocatedIn" to "locatedIn" - it's case-sensitive.  I hope that fixes it for you as well.